# s3fs mount in Redhat 7.7 with IAM role dont work

Tags: amazon-s3, redhat, amazon-iam, fuse, s3fs

I am trying to use s3fs mount following the link as below using IAM role on the EC2 instance spin out of the RHEL 7.7 AMI.
https://medium.com/tensult/aws-how-to-mount-s3-bucket-using-iam-role-on-ec2-linux-instance-ad2afd4513ef

The problem is s3fs mount is not working after following the steps. Can anyone help what is wrong ?

Regards
Pradeep

Comment: Could you post some more details so we know more about what is happening? Does it give an error? What does the directory look like?

Comment: No it doesnt give any error but mount is not working and dont show up in df -kh output. I have used the same bucket and directory as  given in the https://medium.com/tensult/aws-how-to-mount-s3-bucket-using-iam-role-on-ec2-linux-instance-ad2afd4513ef